# How to create partitions in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

After several answers from here, I have found this answer to create partitions in mysql table.

```
ALTER TABLE new
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(originating_date_time)) (
 PARTITION 20220103 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2022-01-04 00:00:00')),
 PARTITION 20220104 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2022-01-05 00:00:00')),
 PARTITION 20220105 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

But now I am getting a syntax error as follows, I have made some several changes like making '' marks in names as well.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '20220103 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2022-01-04 00:00:00')),
 PARTITION 20220104 ' at line 3
```

Can someone help me to get this?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html says:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

So you could name them with a character somewhere in the name like:

```
PARTITION p20220103 ...
```

Or you could delimit them like:

```
PARTITION `20220103` ...
```